# show div content as default upon page load Javascript

Tags: javascript, hide, html-select, show

I want to show one div content (.option-1) when the website is loading.

```js
document.getElementById('target').addEventListener('change', function () {
  let divs = document.querySelectorAll('.initial, .vis'); // grab all divs that have the class "initial" or "vis"
  
  for (let i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    // loop over all divs
    let div = divs[i];
    if (div.classList.contains(this.value)) {
      // the div's class list contains the value of the select box, e.g. "option-1" or "option-2"
      div.classList.remove('initial');
      div.classList.add('vis'); // make the div visible
    } else {
      div.classList.add('initial');
      div.classList.remove('vis'); // otherwise make the divs invisible
    }
  }
  
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <select name="dropdown" id="target">
    <option value="option-1">option1</option>
    <option value="option-2">option2</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="temps">
  <div class="initial option-1">Temp 1</div>
  <div class="initial option-2">Temp 2</div>
</div>

<div class="forms">
  <div class="initial option-1">Form 1</div>
  <div class="initial option-2">Form 2</div>
</div>
```

.initial display none;

```css
.initial {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the first option in the dropdown to run the logic on load, add a load event listener with a DispatchEvent that will emulate a change on the dropdown.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  let event = new Event('change');
  document.getElementById('target').dispatchEvent(event);
});
```